# linear acceleration movement: computation vs modelling

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have a point, which move by linear trajectory with static acceleration. I use 2 approaches to predict point position -

1. computation by formula:

   vx = v0 + a * t;

   x = (vx^2 - v0^2) / (2a)
2. modeling with:

   speed += acceleration;

   position += speed;

And I have different result. Can't understand what's going wrong, please see code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0">
  <canvas id="id" width="1000" height="1000" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <script>
(function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('id');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var fps = 6;

function Point(x, color) {
 this.x = x;
 this.acceleration = {x: 0};
 this.speed = {x: 0};
 this.color = color;
}

Point.prototype.update = function(ctx) {
 this.speed.x += this.acceleration.x;
 this.x += this.speed.x;
}
Point.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(this.x, 30, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
 ctx.fill();
}

var ix = 10;
var p = new Point(ix, 'red');
p.acceleration.x = 1;
var p2 = new Point(ix, 'blue');

function calculateShift(v0, a, t) {
 return (Math.pow((v0 + a * t), 2) - Math.pow(v0, 2)) / (2 * a)
}

var iteration = 0;
function step() {

  iteration++;
  if(iteration > 20) {
 return;
  }
 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  p.update();
  var shift = calculateShift(0, p.acceleration.x, iteration);
  p.draw(ctx);
  p2.x = ix + shift;
  p2.draw(ctx);
  console.log(p.x, p2.x);
}

setInterval(function(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}, 1000 / fps)


})()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Can't understand what's going wrong` - what's going wrong? Your code snippet seems to run fine, so what's the issue?

Comment: Both points should be on same position, but red one going forward

Answer (score 0):

Look like problem was in precision of iterative method. I update example, and look like it work fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0">
  <canvas id="id" width="1000" height="1000" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <script>
(function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('id');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var fps = 60;

function Point(x, color) {
 this.x = x;
 this.acceleration = {x: 0};
 this.speed = {x: 0};
 this.color = color;
}

Point.prototype.update = function(ctx) {
 this.speed.x += this.acceleration.x;
 this.speed.y += this.acceleration.y;
 this.x += this.speed.x;
 this.y += this.speed.y;
}
Point.prototype.draw = function(ctx) {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(this.x, 30, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
 ctx.fill();
}

var ix = 10;
var p = new Point(ix, 'red');
p.lastUpdate = new Date().getSeconds();
p.acceleration.x = 1;
var p2 = new Point(ix, 'blue');

function calculateShift(v0, a, t) {
 return (Math.pow((v0 + a * t), 2) - Math.pow(v0, 2)) / (2 * a)
}

var iteration = 0;
var ts = new Date().getTime();
function step(timestamp) {

  iteration++;
 if(iteration > 2025) {
  return;
 }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
 var s = new Date().getSeconds();
 if(s !== p.lastUpdate) {
 p.lastUpdate = s;
  p.update();
  }
  var shift = calculateShift(0, p.acceleration.x, (new Date().getTime() - ts) / 1000);
  p.draw(ctx);
  p2.x = ix + shift;
  p2.draw(ctx);
  console.log(p.x, p2.x);
}

setInterval(function(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}, 1000 / fps)


})()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```